# Should I use a Model Class for Creating SqlConnection Objects?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an Intranet Website using Active Directory and SQL Server 2008. I created an ASP.NET MVC project and am currently trying to establish a connection to the SQL Database, and since there are different database servers in my company, it would be practical for me to create a Model class that creates the connection strings.

My question is: is this malpractice? I know of Separation of concerns, so I am trying to do this here in order to have a better organization and clearer code but I also feel like this is too much for little functionality.

Let me demonstrate by using an example, this is a function used to create the connection string in the Model class SQLManager.cs :

```
SqlConnection connectWeb= new SqlConnection();//This would be in a constructor
public SqlConnection CreateWebConnection(string SQLServerWeb, string SQLWebDB)
{
    try
    {
        connectWeb.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + SQLServerWeb + ";Initial Catalog=" + SQLWebDB 
                                    + ";Integrated Security=SSPI";
        connectWeb.Open();
        return connectWeb;
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception levée : \n\n" + e.ToString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

It could be practical for me to use this function and just change the parameters when I need to change the connection string. For example I would have the following controller action method:

```
public ActionResult RoleBasedMenu()
{
    SQLManager sqlManager = new SQLManager();
    using(SqlConnection conn = sqlManager.CreateWebConnection("MyDataSource", "MyInitialCatalog"))
    {
        //SQL actions / queries here
    }
```

Another thing that bothers me is opening the connection in a class and closing it in another.
I haven't seen this anywhere so I feel like I'm not doing it right, what do you think?

Comment: When you say "many different servers".. do you mean database servers? Are you saying your site just needs to connect to different database servers to get data?

Comment: I have edited my question. Exactly, I have different database servers, for example one is used for the principal database and another for the backup database.

Comment: I'd use EntityFramework instead, much easier, automatic models, tons of advantages including separate connection information for each dbcontext you want.

Comment: I was thinking of doing that, but from what I've read using EntityFramework means I have to recreate the whole databases right? Because the project has already been in production for over 10 years now but it uses VBScript and has no real design pattern, no SoC, it's quite out of date. So all the DBs are already created and functional

Comment: @JohnPeters forgot to tag you

Comment: No EF does nothing to the DB schema at all.

Comment: Oh that's great, here I go then thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate out the database connections from your controllers. In principal I take the approach of  UI --> Service --> DataLayer. Each controllers action can then call the appropriate service that talks to the correct datalayer which in turn connects to a specific database on whatever server.

I've done an example below which shows how this can be achieved. I've used the term "Role" as your post has a RoleBasedMenu action.

```
public class RoleController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult RoleBasedMenu()
    {
        var myViewModel = new RoleViewModel();
        var myService = new RoleServiceLayer();
        var myRoleDetails = myService.GetRoleDetails();

        myViewModel.Details = myRoleDetails;

        return View("RoleBasedMenu", myViewModel);
    }
}

public class RoleViewModel
{
    public RoleDomainObject Details { get; set; }
}

public class RoleDomainObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //Other Properties here.
}

public class RoleServiceLayer
{
    public RoleDomainObject GetRoleDetails(int roleID)
    {
        var myRole = new RoleDomainObject();
        var dataLayer = new RoleDataLayer();
        var myRoleData = dataLayer.GetRoleDetails(roleID);

        var myDataRow = myRoleData.Tables[0].Rows[0];
        //Set role properties

        return myRole;
    }
}

public class RoleDataLayer
{
    public DataSet GetRoleDetails(int customerID)
    {
        //Connect to DB
        return new DataSet();
    }
}
```

Ideally you would have the service and the datalayer in separate projects.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: I do have one more question, when you say having the service and datalayer in separate projects: what type of project do I have to make? I still have to include them in the same solution right? I have never done this before so it's a bit new to me

Comment: @Flexabustbergson - Sure... in the same solution, just add a new class library project.